# SQL Server database won't update new information

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I don't understand it. This code should work, but there must be something I've done wrong.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

```
string username = tbNewUSER.Text.Trim();
string password = tbNewPass.Text.Trim();
string role = "USER";
string str = "insert into UserValidation (USERNAME, PASSWORD, ROLE) values ('" + username + "','" + password + "','" + role + "')";

MessageBox.Show(username + " Registered", "User registration",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

clsDB.InsUpDel(str);
```

And this is the follow up:

```
public static int InsUpDel(string str)
{
    if (!(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)) 
        conn.Open(); //open connection if closed

    int numRows = 0; //counter that checks number of rows affected in the db

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
        numRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd = null;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        string errorMsg = ex.Message; //more code can be put here               
    }

    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) 
        conn.Close();

    return numRows;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: may want to consider using a parameterized query. Otherwise, have you tried running the generated query?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your try / catch?

Comment: As a side note, try to avoid displaying success messages before the changes are committed.

Comment: Is your connection string to the DB correct? I am not sure how you are opening the connection without a connection string.

Comment: Oh sorry, i have a connectionstring and everything goes smooth but my sql-statment doesn't insert the information.

Comment: Do you have the ability to use SQL Profiler? I suspect the issue is with te DB itself (i.e. trigger, datatype. etc.). If you could put a breakpoint after the string str = , then copy the result to SSMS to run it manually, it may provide helpful feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Side notes:

1. Always use parameters for your queries and never string concatenation. For fun see [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)
2. Do not use static, there are not many places you need this.
3. Dont share database connections, create them and destroy them as needed.
4. Do not store passwords as plain text ever!
5. Do not catch exceptions you do not plan to handle. Log them and rethrow (using `throw;`) or do not catch at all. This last one will help you figure out why "its not working"

Updated code

```
public void UpdateUser() {
  var userModel = new UserModel {
    Username = tbNewUSER.Text.Trim(),
    Password = tbNewPass.Text.Trim(),
    Role = "USER"
  };

  var result = UpdateUser(userModel);
}


public int UpdateUser(UserModel user)
{
    const string str = "insert into UserValidation (USERNAME, PASSWORD, ROLE) values (@userName, @password, @role)";
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string here, hint best to get it from the app.config"))
    using(var command = new SqlCommand(str, conn))
    {
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255) {Value = user.UserName});
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255) {Value = user.Password});
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@role", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255) {Value = user.Role});
      conn.Open();
      return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**UserModel.cs**

```
public class UserModel {
  public string UserName {get;set;}
  public string Password {get;set;}
  public string Role {get;set;}
}
```